# Почему не отправляется форма на postegresql в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Нужно добавлять поля в базу данных PostegreSQL посредством ReactJS
Есть несколько инпутов:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" onChange={e => setMileage(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="text" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="file" onChange={selectFile}/>
    <button onClick={addField}>Добавить</button>
 </form>
```

Функция обработки файлов:

```
const selectFile = e => {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

В которых:

```
const [mileage, setMileage] = useState(0);
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
```

Отправляю:

```
 const addField = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('mileage', `${mileage}`);
        formData.append('name', `${name}` );
        createField(formData).then(data => alert(data))
    }
```

*CreateField это класс в котором я это все делаю*

*Таким способом у меня формы отправлялись которые состояли из одного инпута (с API все нормально)*

Comment: так в чем вопрос то?

Comment: не отправляется форма, не могу понять что я делаю не так. Возможно проблема в том, что я неправильно заполняю массив на отправление